# Facebook respond bad code 503 to my blogger url

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins, blogger

when i use facebook debugger to debug my blog on blogger
the url:http://mantheory.blogspot.com/2012/03/facebook-cant-scrape-this.html

and i got the 503 bad respond code

could someone tell me how to resolve this critical error.
when i change into the default template then  the error was fixed
how do i change my template to get 200 response code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are there other posts there or is that it? I would start by removing anything that looks questionable and rescraping after each removal. Continue until the scrape works and then you'll know what the scraper was upset about.